# Expected expression before

Tags: c

What does this error mean? `error: expected expression before 'Addr'`

```
typedef struct sockaddr_in Addr;

int main() {
    WSADATA Winsock;
    SOCKET Socket, Sub;

    ZeroMemory(&Addr, sizeof(Addr)); // Error occurs here
    return 0;
}
```

I added a comment where the error was occurring at.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact text of the error message?

Comment: @user3386109 It says this: `expected expression before 'Addr'`

Comment: @PeterN see Magisch's answer below. But admittedly the error message is not very clear. Which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually creating a variable you can call the function with, you're just `typedef` 'ing a type of variable that suits your needs. You actually need to declare a variable of that struct type in order for it to work.

Like this:

```
typedef struct sockaddr_in Addr; // Defining what a variable (struct) of type Addr is

int main() {
    WSADATA Winsock;
    SOCKET Socket, Sub;
    Addr testAddr; // Actually declaring a variable of type Addr

    ZeroMemory(&testAddr, sizeof(Addr));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should solve your error:

```
typedef struct sockaddr_in Addr;

int main() {
    WSADATA Winsock;
    SOCKET Socket, Sub;
    Addr addr;

    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(Addr));
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm).